# algorithm for making a red black tree from a binary search tree

Tags: binary-tree

is there any clear algorithm that make a red black tree from a binary search tree?
please help me thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is traverse the nodes in the binary tree, and add each one to a new red-black tree.